# A set is open if its complement is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

I am a little bit confused about the very fundamental property of sets. Is the statement "A set is open if its complement is closed" true?

If both $A$ and $X$ are closed sets in $R^l$, and $A \subset X$. Then $A^c=X-A$, the complement of $A$, is neither open or closed in $X$. For example, $X=\{(x,y) \in R^2| x^2+y^2 \leq 2   \}$, and $A=\{(x,y) \in R^2| x^2+y^2 \leq 1   \}$. Then $X-A=\{(x,y) \in R^2| 1< x^2+y^2 \leq 2   \}$ is neither open or closed.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is the complement relative to? Generally, it is relative to the whole space by default. But then what makes you think $A^c$ is even *in* X?

Comment: I added a concrete example.

Comment: @Vim  You are correct that the set described is *not* the complement of A but the complement of A with respect to X.  But it doesn't matter as that set **IS** open in X.

Comment: X-A **IS** open in X.  It isn't open in R^2 but X- A not equal comp(A) in R^2.  X- A does equal comp(A) in X.  But X-A is **OPEN** in X.

Answer (score 1):

"If both $A$ and $X$ are closed sets in $\mathbb R^l$, and $A\subset X$. Then $A^c=X \setminus A$ is neither open or closed in $X$."

No.  It is open in $X$.

"For example, $X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 |x^2+y^2 \le 2\}$, and $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2\le 1\}.$ Then $X\setminus A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|1 < x^2+y^2\le 2\}$ is neither open or closed."

No.  It is not open in $\mathbb R^2$ (where $X \setminus A$ is *NOT* the complement of $A$).  But it **IS** open in $ X$ (where it *is*).

The points $(w,z)$ where $w^2 + z^2 = 2$ are all interior points of $X \setminus A$.

Let $N(w,z) = \{(x,y) \in X|\sqrt{(x-w)^2 + (y-z)^2} < 1/2\}$ is an open neighborhod *with respect to $X$*.

And $N(w,z) \subset X \setminus A$.  So $(w,z)$ is an interior point $X \setminus A$.

There are no points in $X$ where $x^2 + y^2 > 2$.  So the fact that $X \setminus A$ has an "edge" at $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ does not make it not open.  It can not be thought of as an "edge" because there are no points "beyond" it.

Comment: So the open ball does not have to be full in this case?

Comment: "So the open ball does not have to be full in this case?"  ?????????  I haven't the slightest idea what the heck that means.

Comment: The entire *UNIVERSE* is X. The is absolutely *nothing* in the universe where $x^2+y^2>2$. Nothing. The entire universe consists of of the closed disc with radius 2. A is is the closed disc of radius one. It's complement is everything in the universe that is not on the unit disc.  If it is not on the unit disk then there is a minimum distance between the point and the unit disk. If you take all the points in the universe that are within that distance from that point, none of them are on the unit disk.  So they are in the compliment of the unit disk. So the compliment of the unit disk is open.

Comment: Open neighborhoods constructed for the points $(w,z)$ where $w^2+z^2=2$ can contain points out of $X$, when we are only talking about " open in $X$" . OK, I see, thanks!

Comment: No, they can *not*.  The universe is restricted to X.  An open neighborhood by definition is all the points in X that are within a distance.  You can not include any points that are not in X.  Consider the open interval (0,2) that is an open set.  Now consider the point 1.  Now consider the open neighborhood N(1, 1/4) = (3/4, 1 1/4).  That neighborhood is a subset of (0,2) so 1 is an interior point.  **EXCEPT** $|1 - (1+\frac 18 i)| = 1/8 < 1/4$ but $1 + \frac 18 i \not \in (3/4, 1 1/4)$!  So $N(1,1/4)$ is *no*t a subset of (0,2) after all.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You ask

> Is the statement "A set is open if its complement is closed" true?

The answer is yes. In fact, given the definition of an open set, you can take as definition that a set is closed if the complement is open. That is, given a set $X$ with a topology a set $A$ is closed if $X-A$ is open.

If$A$ and $X$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^l$ (for some $l$), then $A^{c} = \mathbb{R}^l - A$.

Now, if you put a topology on $X$ and you take a subset $Y$ of $X$, then this defines a topology on $Y$ by saying that the open sets in $Y$ are exactly those of the form $Y\cap A$ where $A$ is open in $X$. So your example 
$$
X-A=\{(x,y) \in R^2| 1< x^2+y^2 \leq 2   \}
$$
is indeed open in $X$ (but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course the set $X\setminus A$ above is open in $X$.  I think your confusing that it's not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's  because that you don't take the complement $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ if you take the complement $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$. You will see that it will be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Feel free to use LaTeX (MathJax) when formatting your answers.

Comment: Im sorry i dont  know how to write in correct format

Comment: Take a look at this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks but im using a handset right now

Answer (score 0):

Let M be the ambient space and d the metric on D, you can think of M and d as R, or R^2, or R^3,... with their usual distance functions.

Let's recite our definitions:

A is open if and only if A is a subset of M such that for all $\alpha$ in A, there exists $\delta>0$ so that $N_\alpha(\delta)\subseteq A$. i.e. all of it's members are interior points, so that int (A)=A.

A is a closed subset of M if and only if A is a subset of M such that contains all it's boundary points ($Bd(A)\subseteq A$).

Here's the proof:

Let A$\subseteq M$ and $A^C$ be closed. Want to prove A is open using our definition of open above. We need to show for all $\alpha\in A$, there exists $\delta$>0 such that $N_\alpha(\delta)\subseteq A$:

Let $\alpha\in A$. We know $\alpha $ is not a boundary pointof A because if it were, it would also be a boundary point of $A^C$, which is a closed set, and contains all of it's boundary points which would include $\alpha$, which is impossible since $\alpha$ can not be in both A and it's complement simultaneously. Thus $\alpha$ is not a boundary point of A. Therefore, by the negation of the definition of a boundary point, there must exist $\delta>0$ so that no elements of $A^C$ are in $N_\alpha(\delta)$. Ask yourself this: if the elements of $N_\alpha(\delta)$ are not in $A^C$, where must they be? Right smack inside of A, of course. Thus for all $\alpha$ in A, there is $\delta$>0 so that $N_\alpha(\delta)\subseteq A$

Thus we've established A$\subseteq M$ and for all $\alpha$ in A, there is $\delta$>0 so that $N_\alpha(\delta)\subseteq A$. This means A is open.

Q.E.D.

Adam V. Nease